# Typing issues with arrays declared in a web service interface

Tags: c#

I am trying to port some VB.NET code which used these global variables docArray, and docputResponse to C# without global variables and trying to pass around to various methods in two projects.

These are of the following types which I declared in my web service Gilbane.RREM.Interfaces namespace:

```
 Gilbane.Common.SSHIP_Prod_Interface5.documentValue[] docArray
    Gilbane.Common.SSHIPDocumentServiceProd.putDocumentSvcResponse[] docputResponse
```

The first method I am trying to pass to, I have declared these by reference since they will be changed down the line:

```
public bool SendDocument(interface5toSSHIP row, FileType file, int i, ref Gilbane.Common.SSHIP_Prod_Interface5.documentValue[] docArray, ref Gilbane.Common.SSHIPDocumentServiceProd.putDocumentSvcResponse[] docputResponse)
```

I kept getting errors until I declared these at the top of my web service:

```
 Gilbane.Common.SSHIP_Prod_Interface5.documentValue[] docArray = new documentValue[7];
        Gilbane.Common.SSHIPDocumentServiceProd.putDocumentSvcResponse[] docputResponse = new putDocumentSvcResponse[7];
```

When I do that, it won't let me pass just docArray.

```
  public bool SendDocument(interface5toSSHIP row, FileType file, int i, ref Gilbane.Common.SSHIP_Prod_Interface5.documentValue[] docArray, ref Gilbane.Common.SSHIPDocumentServiceProd.putDocumentSvcResponse[] docputResponse)
```

It says Parameter docArray hides field 'documentValue[] Gilbane.RREM.Interface5.docArray.' Same for docputResponse.

Then in SendDocument, I need to call a method:

```
if (document.SendDocument(ba, appId, "GILBANE_I5_", file, ref docId, 5, InterfaceType.Interface5, ref this.docArray, ref this.docputResponse, i))
```

Arument 8 should not be passed with the ref keyword
Argument 9 should not be passed with the ref keyword

document.SendDocument is spec'd as:

```
public bool SendDocument(byte[] fileToSend, string appId, string filePrefix, FileType file, ref string docId,
            int interfaceId, InterfaceType typeOfInterface, ref SSHIP_Prod_Interface5.documentValue[] docArray, ref SSHIPDocumentServiceProd.putDocumentSvcResponse[] putResponse, int i)
```

Can someone pleae help me get this typing correct and these calls working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not need to pass the arrays by ref if your intention is to only view/modify its contents. Simply removing the ref keyword from your method declarations and calls should fix the issue.

Comment: You're right! It got rid of the typing issues. Now the only barrier to compilation is Error 12 Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\Gilbane.Common.dll" to "bin\Debug\Gilbane.Common.dll". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\Gilbane.Common.dll' because it is being used by another process. Gilbane.Common
I think I might have a circular reference

Comment: I've received weird errors like that from Visual Studio before. My issue was it was simply tripping over itself and restarting VS did the trick. Don't know if its the same issue you're experiencing though.